# Screen detection and mouse reverse (x & y axis)

Tags: mouse, screen, 19.04

I installed ubuntu 19.04 OS on my laptop.

The installation went well but when I booted in and the screen was backwards. I signed in as root and the screen flipped back but the mouse is reverse (x & y axis).

When I move my mouse left it moves right when I move it down it moves up. If I want to press a button at the upper right I need to press it at the down left.

The screen is acting backwordes (x & y axis)but I see the graphics straight and the mouse is acting backwordes.

I installed ubuntu 19.04 again with a fresh installation. I have the same problem as before.

I did some googling and find something about the Matrix

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                       id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP HD Webcam: HP HD Webcam                id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I went through my devises, one by one and all had `1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1` case which is supposed to be normal!, i tried changing some to be `-1 0 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1` but nothing worked.

Also it's the second time I install ubuntu 19.04, i had them installed the day they released and i didn't have that problem!

Answer (score 0):

not a solution maybe but I cannot comment yet.

try setting props to all zeros, which works the same for me as the  normal matrix that you have with some 1's

try

```
xinput disable <id>
```

to make sure that  the real mouse ID is  used. and to get it back

```
xinput enable <id>
```

you probably already have this link
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/InputCoordinateTransformation

Answer (score 0):

If all your pointing devices are using the matrix `1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1`, which is

```
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

that's supposed to be normal.

Assuming you're certain that the pointing device you're using was one you checked, I've no idea why it's reversed, but you should be able to undo it by reversing again. You'll want this matrix:

```
-1  0 0
 0 -1 0
 0  0 1
```

which you can set with a command similar to

```
xinput set-prop "PS/2 Generic Mouse" "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" -1 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 1
```

---

Others:

- Flip just y axis: `1 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 1` (useful for games which don't provide the option)
- Back to normal: `1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1`

Things are different if your regular matrix isn't the identity, which may be the case if you have a rotated display, or possibly in other circumstances.